# Eigen: m(:, v > 0) and m(:, [1,3])

Tags: matlab, eigen

I'm trying to implement Matlab's m(:, v > 0) and m(:,[1,3]) in Eigen. So far I got the following functions:

```
MatrixXd select_cols(const MatrixXd src, const Matrix<bool, 1, Dynamic> cond)                                                                                              
{                                                                                                                                                                          
    MatrixXd dst(src.rows(), cond.count());                                                                                                                                
    unsigned int i = 0;                                                                                                                                                    

    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < cond.cols(); j++) {                                                                                                                       
        if (cond(0,j)) {                                                                                                                                                   
            dst.col(i++) = src.col(j);                                                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                                                                  

    }                                                                                                                                                                      
    return dst;                                                                                                                                                            
}

MatrixXd select_cols(const MatrixXd src, const Matrix<unsigned int, 1, Dynamic> idx)                                                                                       
{                                                                                                                                                                          
    MatrixXd dst(src.rows(), idx.size());                                                                                                                                  

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < idx.size(); ++i) {                                                                                                                        
        dst.col(i) = src.col(idx[i]);                                                                                                                                      
    }                                                                                                                                                                      

    return dst;                                                                                                                                                            
}
```

However, I thought that the following snippet will work, but it does't:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd m1(3,3);                                                                                                                                                           
Eigen::Matrix<unsigned int, 1, Eigen::Dynamic> v(3);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
m1 << 1,2,3,                                                                                                                                                               
      4,5,6,                                                                                                                                                               
      7,8,9;                                                                                                                                                               

v  << 2,0,2;                                                                                                                                                               

Eigen::MatrixXd m2 = Eigen::select_cols(m1, v.array() > 1);
```

There is the error:

```
utest.cpp:88:62: error: call of overloaded ‘select_cols(Eigen::MatrixXd&, const Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<std::binder2nd<std::greater<unsigned int> >, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<unsigned int, 1, -0x00000000000000001> > >)’ is ambiguous
utest.cpp:88:62: note: candidates are:
common.h:29:14: note: Eigen::MatrixXd Eigen::select_cols(Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::Matrix<unsigned int, 1, -0x00000000000000001>)
common.h:32:14: note: Eigen::MatrixXd Eigen::select_cols(Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::Matrix<bool, 1, -0x00000000000000001>)
```

Comment: `m(:, m > 0)` doesn't really make sense in Matlab. `m > 0` will have the same dimensions as `m`. So if `m` is a 2D matrix, then you are trying to choose the columns with a logical 2D matrix which shouldn't work. So what behavior are you expecting from it?

Comment: I suppose you may either be looking for `m(m>0)`, `m(:,any(m>0))`, `m(:,all(m>0))` or `m(:,sum(m>0))`

Answer (score 0):

To replicate Matlab's *m(:,[1,3])* in Eigen you can simply use the *.block()* method from the matrix class:

```
MatrixXd m(3,4);
m << 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12;
...

MatrixXd sub_m = m.block(0,0, m.rows(),3);

...
std::cout << m << std::endl << sub_m << std::endl;
```

The output will be:

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9 10 11 12
1  2  3
5  6  7
9 10 11
```

Regards.